# Speech recognizer on two buttons to two edittexts

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have two edittext boxes and a button for each.

When I click the first button I want to envoke the speech recognizer and the result goes into the first editext box and the 2nd button fills the 2nd edittext box.

I'm using the following code

```
public void speech1(View view) {
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void speech2(View view) {
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.",        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    if(REQUEST_CODE==1){
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.speechText1);
        editText.setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }

    if(REQUEST_CODE==2){        
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.speechText2);
        editText.setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

It wont fill in the correct edittext box just leaves them blank have been looking for a tutorial but cant find any examples of two speech inputs

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in your life is described by tutorial, sometimes you want to think yourself. In your particular case your issue is that you are comparing a global variable RESULT_CODE instead of a local argument of onActivityResult,

```
if(REQUEST_CODE==1){
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.speechText1);
```

must instead be

```
if(requestCode==1){
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.speechText1);
```

The request code is passed to you through the argument, you need to use it.